# Isn't this phrase an essential part?

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation

[Source](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/stories-poems/scarlett)

Please read the transcript for reference.

> I’ve already heard stories about
>   her grandfather. He was from Scotland; he was
>   a sailor, **but not a very good sailor,** so he only
>   got as far as Portsmouth, a big navy town on
>   the south coast of England, not very far from
>   Scotland at all.

The bold part seems like an essential phrase to me. Since removing it should not change the meaning, let's see

> He was a sailor so he only got as far as Portsmouth.

Then the last two phrases are also non-essential so I avoid writing them. I think it should be like:

> He was
>   a sailor, **but not a very good sailor** so he only
>   got as far as Portsmouth.

A similar one from the same:

> But I know that her mum
>   was from somewhere that was Germany **, and
>   then became Poland,** so she’s really German, I
>   suppose.

Again the bold part seems to be essential to me.

What do you think about these construction?

Comment: "*that* then became Poland,"

Comment: The fence is high, **but (it is) not too high**, so you can manage to jump over it.  It is essential in that it negates an aspect of the preceding predicate.  The river is shallow but crocodile-infested.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction between being between commas and being essential. You are perhaps thinking of relative clauses, where commenting (non-restrictive, non-essential) clauses are set off with commas. But that distinction only applies for relative clauses.